# If $\mathbb{E}(X_n)=\mu<\infty$, is it true that $\mathbb{E}|X_n-\mu|=0$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

Here, $X_n$ is a sequence of random variables with finite mean $\mu$ such that $X_n=f(Y_1,...,Y_n)$ where $Y_1,...,Y_n$ are IID random variables with finite mean and variance

Now by definition of the absolute value, in the case where $X_n-\mu>0$, clearly $\mathbb{E}|X_n-\mu|=\mathbb{E}(X_n-\mu)=0$.

In the case $X_n-\mu<0$, we have $\mathbb{E}|X_n-\mu|=\mathbb{E}(-X_n+\mu)=0$. So this would imply $\mathbb{E}|X_n-\mu|=0$.

However I feel like this isn't true? I say this because of Markov's inequality: $\mathbb{P}(X\geq k)\leq \frac{\mathbb{E}(X)}{k}$ for positive $X$ and $k$.

Applying Markov's inequality in this case implies $\mathbb{P}(|X_n-\mu|\geq k)\leq \frac{\mathbb{E}|X_n-\mu|}{k}$ (which my reasoning) $=0$.

But surely the probability that $|X_n-\mu|\geq k$ for $k>0$ must be greater than $0$? Surely, $|X_n-\mu|$ cannot be less than $k$ always?

Comment: Your question is unclear. To answer your question in the title take  $\mathbb P\{X_n=\pm 1\}=\frac{1}{2}$ for a counter example.

Comment: In fact $\mathbb EY=0$ for a non-negative random variable iff $Y$ vanishes almost surely, so any non-constant random variable with mean is a counterexample. With regards to your attempt you cannot split the expectation into cases like that; $\mathbb E|X-\mu|$ is a fixed number.